# Better way of viewing wide code blocks

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I get why you can't just scroll code horizontally (that could make it difficult to switch between questions and answers) but the way it is now is pretty annoying. I'd like to be able to read the question/answer *while* looking at the code, and not have that all disappear.

Why not make it that a tap makes the code scrollable, and another tap makes it unscrollable? That way code blocks won't prevent question/answer toggling, while still allowing us to look at code while seeing the rest of the post.

Comment: For comparison, the iOS app scrolls code horizontally, and has buttons at the top to switch between question and answers. You could swipe from just the edge to switch, but I believe they are removing that in the next version.

Comment: The latest version is now displaying the question and its answers on the same view (vertical `ScrollView`), replacing the question/answers tabs, and thus, this feature-request might be obsolete until the request is updated.